# Login failed for user 'id/id2'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I was going to check if my database is connecting to my project in vb.net, but it's seems like there's a problem on my code or to my SQL server. It always shows me a message "Login failed for user 'id/id2'".

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = (local);Database=OJT;integrated security=true"
    Try
        sqlconn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Connection to Sql Server Failed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Try
    Me.Text = "You are successfully connected to Sql Server"
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one instead :

```
"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=OJT;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=(Your User ID);Password=(Your Password)"
```

hopes that it solve your problem. Good Day!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
sqlconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=OJT;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: it say the same thing ,  "Login failed for user 'id/id2'". darn!

Comment: can you give a more details this connection? try to use the `Server Instance` → `Data Source=YourPcName/ServerName`